# Is there an Azure Dev Ops pipeline variable for current pull request number?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, devops

I want to use the current pull request number in my web.config file when I publish my website. Is there a variable that I can access that stores that value?

Comment: @stuartd No I mean pull request. I want to use it as the third number in my version number. For right now that will do for my purposes but I dont want to update the web.config file manually, I would rather have the pipeline do this for me.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET No I wouldnt commit it, it would update it after its been pushed out. So the repo would just have 0 in it, but the released version would get the updated number. Thanks for the advice anyway.

Comment: Found [File transforms and variable substitution (in Azure Pipelines)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops) - might do it, if it can access build variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables)) the PR number is stored in: `System.PullRequest.PullRequestNumber`

That being said, you usually wouldn't deploy during a PR/CI build, only during a build off the stable branch. This is what "release" pipelines are for.

Comment: `Build.SourceVersion` - the latest commit - seems more sensible anyway. Not all commits are from PRs.

Comment: FWIW, my usual versioning method is to store the current version as a build variable, then increment after adding a feature, introducing a breaking change, or actually releasing. This way I can do semantic versioning

Comment: If you're publishing after every build, though, knowing what commit/PR that was based on does sound like it could be useful

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I guess my hang up is the manual part. I would like a solution that works on its own automatically without me or my other team mate having to remember to update that number ourselves manually.

Comment: @CameronBelt The thing is that there is no way to get a correct semantic version automatically. Only the programmer can know which number(s) should be changed. I do have the pipeline append the build number for pre-release versions though.